# Table inside enumeration: How to align vertically when using booktabs' \toprule?

Tags: tables, enumerate, booktabs

I want to display a table inside an `enumerate` environment such that the first row aligns with the item label. My current code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setenumerate{listparindent=\parindent, parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large\sffamily\bfseries \alph*)]
  \item
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
    \toprule
    $m$ & $P(R=a,M=m)$ & $P(R=b,M=m)$ & $P(R=c,M=m)$ \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
    2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \item
  \( 
    \displaystyle
    P(0) = P(0|B) P(B) + P(0|G) P(G)
  \)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately (despite using the `t` option of the `tabular` environment), the alignment is not as expected due to the `\toprule` command. If I remove it, everthing is fine. How may I solve this?

Furthermore, how can I center the table horizontally within the current line? I tried to use a floating table by surrounding it with `\begin{table}\end{table}`, but this changed the vertical placement even more.

Comment: The issue you're looking to fix isn't really specific to `\toprule`: It also occurs when the standard LaTeX `\hline` command is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to forcefully adjust the first line to align with the label. Below I've introduced `ttabular` that inserts this vertical adjustment (comprised of a regular baseline skip plus all the rule widths that make up `\toprule`<sup>*</sup>). Horizontal centering is obtain using an `\hfill<item>\hfill\null` approach. You can also use a box of width `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,booktabs}

\setenumerate{listparindent=\parindent, parsep=0pt}

\newenvironment{ttabular}[2][c]
  {\begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
     \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\abovetopsep-\belowrulesep-\heavyrulewidth]
  }{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large\sffamily\bfseries \alph*)]
  \item \hfill%
  \begin{ttabular}[t]{cccc}
    \toprule
    $m$ & $P(R=a,M=m)$ & $P(R=b,M=m)$ & $P(R=c,M=m)$ \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
    2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{ttabular}%
  \hfill\null%

  \item
  \( 
    \displaystyle
    P(0) = P(0|B) P(B) + P(0|G) P(G)
  \)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that the vertical adjustment causes the `tabular` to rise quite high, which may overlap with contents above it. In that sense, you'll have to make adjustments to accommodate for that as well, if needed.

<sup>*</sup> One of these lengths `\abovetopsep` is actually set to 0pt by default.

Answer (score 7):

You can emulate what `array` does with `\firsthline`; however, the tabular will most likely clash with the preceding material and you have to add some vertical space anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firsttoprule}{%
  \addlinespace[\dimexpr-\aboverulesep-\belowrulesep-\heavyrulewidth-\ht\@arstrutbox]
  \toprule}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent, parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}[
  align=left,
  label=\large\sffamily\bfseries\alph*),
  before=\vspace{1.5ex}
]
\item
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
  \firsttoprule
  $m$ & $P(R=a,M=m)$ & $P(R=b,M=m)$ & $P(R=c,M=m)$ \\
  \midrule
  1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
  2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\item
  \( 
    \displaystyle
    P(0) = P(0|B) P(B) + P(0|G) P(G)
  \)
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\setenumerate` is a deprecated command.

Answer (score 6):

You may also use the `adjustbox` package by adjusting the vertical alignment:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent, parsep=0pt} % edited as per @egreg comment

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large\sffamily\bfseries \alph*)]
  \item
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t} % The key value, t, adjusts the vertical alignment
    \makebox[\linewidth]{       % Causes the centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    %\noalign{\vskip-.85ex}      % Uncomment to see the second output
    \toprule
    $m$ & $P(R=a,M=m)$ & $P(R=b,M=m)$ & $P(R=c,M=m)$ \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
    2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
    \end{adjustbox}
  \item
  \( 
    \displaystyle
    P(0) = P(0|B) P(B) + P(0|G) P(G)
  \)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the `adjustbox` package before. I picked Werner's answer, though, because I wanted the text of the first row to be on the same baseline as the item label. Your answer might still be helpful in similar cases, so +1. ;)

Comment: @ph4nt0m see updated answer.